# Cannot access host machine with its private-ip from docker container in swarm ingress mode in Windows Server 2019

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, windows-server-2019

I have a docker swarm with following (Azure VMs) hosts,

1. leader, 10.0.1.4
2. worker-1, 10.0.1.5
3. worker-2, 10.0.1.6


   I have installed the 'Mssql Xxpress 2017 Server' on worker-1 (10.0.1.5) and the DB can be accessed via port 1433.

When I deploy the docker swarm services,

- whatever the containers that get deployed in worker-1 (10.0.1.5) in which the DB server is listening on 1433, cannot access the DB (give connection timeout error).
- The other containers can access the DB without an issue.

> Simply the container cannot access the its host. Base image is
>   servercore:ltsc2019.

I tried 'docker exec -it  powershell' and Tried 'Test-NetConnection 10.0.1.5 -Port 1433' on the containers that are running on worker-1 (i. 10.0.1.5) got TcpSucceed: False

But when I try the same on other containers (which are not running on worker-1) got TcpSucceed: True.

PS C:\enactor\enactor-suite> docker info

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 4
Server Version: 18.09.8
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: process
Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
Operating System: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.615)
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 8GiB
Name: Enactor
ID: 3T3Y:S6CD:63QF:PQFE:C6Q3:JL3M:3GEJ:AG4I:ID2Q:OVDY:L5C6:A5QO
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 private_ip=10.0.1.5
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: 1/ Check if services using db use the same network defined in DB service. 2/ Check if you are using service name (docker service) as HOST_NAME to access to DB from others services.